# Стандартный фон элемента ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно, чтобы на небольшой промежуток времени подсветился один из элементов ListView. Сделал через setBackgroundColor, но понял, что не могу вернуться к дефолтному. Как это можно это сделать или есть способы сделать это проще? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

**UPDATE**
Ответ, помеченный верным, неплох, но, основываясь на нем, сделал именно для своей ситуации немного по-другому. Прикладываю вариант.

```
color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
        Drawable background = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getBackground();
        if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
            color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();

        lstView.getChildAt(num).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorGreen));
        AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f);
        animation1.setDuration(2000); //время подсветки
        lstView.getChildAt(num).startAnimation(animation1);

        animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                lstView.getChildAt(num).setBackgroundColor(color);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: вместо бэкграунда вы можете использовать свойство `setSelection()`, при необходимости кастомизации написать свой селектор для айтема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно попробовать так (небольшой хак конечно), только это будет подсветка по клику

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
            adapter.setLightItemByPosition(position);
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.colorAccent));
            AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f);
            animation1.setDuration(5000); //время подсветки
            view.startAnimation(animation1);

            animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this,R.color.white));
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

либо в адаптере

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if (position == lightPosition) {
        lightPosition = -1;
        lightView(view);
    }

    viewHolder.text.setText(items.get(position));

    return view;
}

private void lightView(final View view) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorAccent));
    AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f);
    animation1.setDuration(5000); //время подсветки
    view.startAnimation(animation1);

    animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {//возвращаем дефолтный цвет по истечению времени
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.white));
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });
}

public void setLightItemByPosition(int position) {
    lightPosition = position;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

и уже у адаптера вызываете setLightItemByPosition(int position).

Mожно все это обернуть для нескольких позиций в getView заменить на

```
  if (lightPositions.size() != 0) {
        for (Integer lightPosition: lightPositions) {
            if (lightPosition == position) {
                lightView(view);
                lightPositions.remove(lightPosition);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

изменить метод установки подсветки на

```
 public void setLightItemByPositions(List<Integer> positions) {
    lightPositions = positions;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```